# Is it possible to create folders of tiles?

Tags: tiles

I use a lot of tiles in my Start Screen.

Many of them are just shortcuts to apps or games I frequently use.

They end up occupying a lot of space on the screen even when its minimal size.

Can I group them in something like folders in iOS or Android and categorize them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with an application called App folder if you have the Lumia `Amber` update. To check if you do, follow [these instructions](http://www.nokia.com/au-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142009).

Then install [App folder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/app-folder/7d2e7de3-95e7-4143-8a9d-aedf8c3f901e). This app will allow you to create a folder with a selection of apps in it.

> App Folder. A new Start screen feature for grouping similar apps and settings, making it easier to personalize and organize your phone.

[image]

### Edit

Thanks to @caschw I've realised that the below information is incorrect, but I'll leave it here so his comment makes sense. The post was update to the `Amber` update.

The upcoming Nokia release "[Lumia Black](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2014/01/09/nokia-kicks-off-lumia-black-software-update-with-new-features-apps.aspx)" looks to deliver this.

Comment: You do not need the black update. This works on all of my amber phones.

Comment: Similar App by SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS is also available.
[App Folder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/app-folder/1a248adb-1429-45ea-a507-f3d5f4cad58c)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Mac, Samsung has also released a very similar [App-Folder app](http://www.windowsphone.com/nl-nl/store/app/app-folder/1a248adb-1429-45ea-a507-f3d5f4cad58c).